# 'return accept int, return int' contains no buildables

Tags: c, xcode, osx-lion

I am new to writing code and this is my first question on this site so please forgive my ignorance if there is an obvious solution for this.

When I compile and run the code in Xcode I get a message I have never seen before. I think it has more to do with the return statement but can't seem to fix it by changing the return statement. This is an example from my text book so I would think the logic is sound. I have tried running this code on more than one computer(all mac OSX) with the same results.I have tried different IDEs including codeRunner and Xcode 4.6.3 and 3.4.? and the latest release.

Can anyone tell me what the following message means? It seems not to be a compiling error but a message in a popup window.

THE MESSAGE
"**The scheme 'return accept int, return int' contains no buildables that can be built for the SDKs supported by the run destination My Mac 64–bit. Make sure your targets all specify SDKs that are supported by this version of Xcode**."

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int cubed(int var);
float main (){
    int x;
    printf("Please enter an integer \n");
    scanf(" %d", &x);
    printf(" %d ^ 3 = %d \n",x, cubed(x));
    return 1;
}

float cubed(int var){ //This line was "int cubed(int var)" before I started playing with it.

    float result;
    result = pow(var, 3.0);
    return(result);// I get the same message if I take out this line

}
```

I realized the issue with the return type conflict and have changed the code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <math.h>
int cubed(int var);
int main (){
    int x;
    printf("Please enter an integer \n");
    scanf(" %d", &x);
    printf(" %d ^ 3 = %d \n",x, cubed(x));
    return 0;
}

int cubed(int var){
    float result;
    result = pow(var, 3.0);
    return(result);
}
```

I now know that it is a setting issue within Xcode.
 I have attached a series of screen shots illustrating the message I was receiving, what I did, and the new error I'm getting now. I was able to get the code to run in the IDE CodeRunner but not Xcode.

-- I guess I don't have the reputation points to post images. --

But now I get this new message.
  " your mac runs an osx that is lower than the minimum require for your project.--Change your project's minimum deployment target or upgrade your version of OS X."

Now what?

I think I had changed the return type in the function header when troubleshooting early on but forgot about the function prototype, things get a bit confusing when I have to jumping from one editor to another to another trying to troubleshoot. My class uses Dev C++ and sometimes this causes me some confusion.

Can anyone tell me how I could fix this new issue or how to avoid it in the future?

Comment: The standard function `main` should look like `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Comment: In C, `main` **must always return `int`** ([according to the C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf#page=24)). Therefore, `float main()` is not valid C. I'm unsure if this is the source of your problem or not (might be, the error message is pretty cryptic to me), but you should change it nonetheless.

Comment: `cubed` returns a `float`. Therefore your format specifier should be `%f`, not `%d`. `%d` is for `int`.

Comment: BTW - the actual error message has nothing to do with your code. It's a problem with the project setup.

Comment: @rmaddy: `int main(void)` is actually also acceptable if command-line arguments are not needed.

Comment: Thank you all for you useful suggestions. I came to the same conclusion as @rmaddy. What dose this setting really mean and ware can I find relevant info on how to change it?